# Solving a particular transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find the chemical potential as a function of number density, the equation of which is
\begin{equation}
\frac{n}{2\pi l_{B}^2} = \int_{-\Delta}^{\Delta}d\epsilon \frac{e^{-\epsilon^2/w^2}}{e^{{(\epsilon-\omega_{L}+\delta\mu)}/kT}+1},
\end{equation}
where $\omega_{L}=(2n+1)\hbar\omega_{c}$, and $\Delta = w+kT$.

I would like to solve for $\delta\mu$ as a function of $n$ for different values of parameters $w, kT.$

```
(*kT is set to 1. \hbar\omega_{c} is set to 1. 2\pi l_{B}^2 is set to 1.*)

In[113]:= e[w_, T_, M_, i_] := -(w + T) + 2 (w + T) i/M; (*discretize e*) 

In[95]:= 
S[w_, T_, M_, dmuu_, NN_] := 
 2 ((w + T)/M)
   Sum[1/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] w) Exp[(-e[w, T, M, i])^2/w^2]/(
    Exp[(e[w, T, M, i] - (NN + 0.5) + dmuu)/T] + 1), {i, 0, M}] (*RHS of equation defined in the text*)  

In[143]:= N[ S[1, 1, 50, 0.1, 10]]

Out[143]= 21.1583

Solve[(2 10 + 1) - S[1, 1, 50, dmuu, 10] == 0, dmuu ] (*does not evaluate*)
```

Unfortunately `Solve` takes too long and I abort the evaluation.

Alternatively I can do a low-temperature expansion (Sommerfeld expansion),
\begin{equation}
\int d\epsilon \phi(\epsilon)\frac{1}{e^{{(\epsilon-\mu)}/kT}+1} = \int^{\mu}d\epsilon\phi(\epsilon)+\frac{\pi^2}{6}(kT)^2\phi^{'}(\mu)+\frac{7\pi^2}{360}(kT)^4\phi^{'''}(\mu)+\dots
\end{equation}
and find the chemical potential $\mu$ as a series expansion in $\frac{kT}{\mu_{0}}$, where at $\mu = \mu_{0}$,  $n = n_{0}$.($kT\ll \mu_{0}$)

But I was wondering if there is a direct way to solve the transcendental equation.

Thanks for your help.

Edit : Thanks to Daniel Huber, `FindRoot` is useful in finding the root of the transcendental equation. `FindRoot` returns a list of replacement rules. I need to input the result of `FindRoot` to a function, i.e.,

```
(* f[x_] := FindRoot[g[x,u],{u,0}] *)
(* FindRoot returns a list of replacement for particular values of x*)
(*I would like to input f[x] into another function F[f[x]]*)

dmu[w_, T_, NN_] := 
 FindRoot[(2 NN + 1) - S[w, T, 100, dmuu, NN], {dmuu, 0} ]
DD[w_, T_, mu_, M_, NN_] := -2 ((w + T)/M)
   Sum[1/(Sqrt[Pi] w) Exp[-e[w, T, M, i]^2/w^2] - E^((
    e[w, T, M, i] - (NN + 0.5) + mu)/
    T)/((1 + E^((e[w, T, M, i] - (NN + 0.5) + mu)/T))^2 T), {i, 0, 
    M}]   


A[w_, T_, NN_, Ex_] := Ex (1 - 1/2 Ex DD[w, T, dmu[w, T, NN], 10] )(*dmu returns a replacement list for particular values. Is there any way to input into a function.*)
```

How do I convert ```FindRoot``` for variable parameters into an input for another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at:

```
Solve[(2 10 + 1) - S[1, 1, 50, dmuu, 10] == 0, dmuu ]
```

This is nothing else than a root search. If we in addition plot "S":

```
Plot[(2 10 + 1) - S[1, 1, 50, dmuu, 10], {dmuu, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

and if we are only are interested in the above root, we may write:

```
FindRoot[(2 10 + 1) - S[1, 1, 50, dmuu, 10], {dmuu, 0}]
```

(* {dmuu -> 4.54994} *)

Comment: how do I assign a variable to have the output of FindRoot. I want to substitute the value of find root as an input to a function.

Comment: variable= dmuu /. {dmuu -> 4.54994}